# Flask Sqlalchemy throwing error when trying to import db variable on python cli

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can not even get off the ground with this one.  Flask is not my first framework, but it is new to me since so many updates have went by. ok, so my problem is that I am running into this error when I am running my python file within the cli to import the db variable to work with it using sqlite.

```
>>> from __init__ import db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*myusername*\Desktop\*appname*\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ImportError: cannot import name 'SQLAlchemy' from 'sqlalchemy' (C:\Users\*myusername*\Envs\*appname*\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\__init__.py)
```

My code is listed below, it isn't much but this is all I like from finishing my project.  If anyone has any pointers here let me know.  I am guessing it's something simple (it usually is) that I am just overlooking.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask('*appname*')

# Database functionality

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']= 'sqlite:///C:/Users/*myusername*/Desktop/*appname*/'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class usersTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.Text)
    lname = db.Column(db.Text)
    email = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    username = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    password = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)
    joined = db.Column(db.Date)
```

Thanks in advance guys.  Normally my backend language is PHP, so I am branching out and this is really starting to get on my nerves lol.

Comment: are you using flask_sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to install Flask-SQLAlchemy library using: `pip install flask-sqlalchemy`

Then import it like this in your code, `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`

If you want to learn more, check this [minimal application](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) using flask-sqlalchemy.

Comment: I get this error when I run it now, I am not trying to sound needy but I can't wrap my head around this for some reason:

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'

Comment: I did install flask_sqlalchemy

Comment: sorry wrong library. flask-sqlalchemy is the correct one

Comment: from flask-sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: its saying the hyphen is invalid syntax

Comment: `from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy`. replace your hypen into underscore

Comment: and also change this code `app = Flask('*appname*')` into `app = Flask(__name__)`

Comment: That is just a placeholder for this site.  Its name is there

Comment: The underscore fixed it.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Problem mate, Goodluck in your application.